# ChromeDriver fails to run Chrome in Windows 7. Why?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can't make chromedriver work in Windows 7

Application (c#) launches Chrome Driver:

(a) `driver = new ChromeDriver();` 
It works fine, except in Windows 7. In Windows 7 (64x):

1. chromedriver.exe window shows up
2. some delay
3. then line (a) produces Exception:

> OpenQA.SeleniumWebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service
>   on...

There's nothing in Chromedriver log except of:

> [1565170796.674][INFO]: Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68
>   (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864})
>   [1565170796.674][INFO]: Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and
>   related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

My application is not a service and this is not a Session 0 problem, AFAIK. Other things I tried that didn't help:

> chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
>   chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox"); Reinstall Chrome from
>   alternate installer Set property in Environment Variables Update
>   chromedriver from 75 to 76

I expect it to open Chrome like it does in Windows 10 or 8.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you manually start the ChromeDriver does it close right away? If so it's nothing with your code and something is blocking the WebDriver from starting on the port it wants to use. It may be firewall or group policy related.

I've seen this before at work where due to policy restrictions files executed off of a network drive cannot open ports on a Windows 10 machine.